# Will IServiceProvider be disposed when the main application thread crashes?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

So I know that IServiceProvider will be disposed at application shutdown (clean) and everything it is managing will be disposed as part of that operation. But what if the main thread throws? Will IServiceProvider still be disposed?

The reason that I ask is logging. In other types of applications, I would normally wrap the main process (in the main method) with a try catch and then in a finally block, I'd make sure the log buffer was flushed. So if the main thread throws, the logs always get flushed.

I could still do this to be sure, but that would mean trying to find reference to the container that is created during startup and that feels a bit kludgy. I feel like it's an obvious thing to have ASP's process wrapped internally to ensure this behavior, so it probably does, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: When `Main` exits, whether due to app shutdown or a thrown exception, the process is done. Since everything is process-bound, disposing is not an issue. All memory and resources consumed by the process goes away when the process goes away. However, an exception reaching `Main` is really only going to happen if there's it's thrown in app startup. The exception handling middleware is going to catch anything else, keeping the entire process from crashing.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that all resources would be disposed, but I guess any follow-on actions that are normally run in those Dispose() methods (like flushing the log buffer) wouldn't have an opportunity to run. So it sounds like the exception filter is my only real option?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a global exception handler middleware during pipeline config to handle any otherwise unhandled exceptions. In Configure() you just go app.UseExceptionHandler and pass your custom handler (or lambda).